# CUPS installing using repository

Tags: linux, git, printing, printer, cups

I want to get printer state from CUPS. To do that , I am trying to customize CUPS's source code. So I can send a message to my front-end.

I have downloaded CUPS repository from `gitub` [Apple's Cups repo](https://github.com/apple/cups/archive/master.zip).
Then unzip it and ran

`./configure`

I am getting following error.

> auth.c: In function ‘cups_crypt’: auth.c:2017:5: error: unknown type
>   name ‘_cups_md5_state_t’
>        _cups_md5_state_t state;  /* Primary MD5 state info */
>        ^ auth.c:2018:5: error: unknown type name ‘_cups_md5_state_t’
>        _cups_md5_state_t state2;  /* Secondary MD5 state info */

If I just use `yum install cups` it works fine.

What went wrong here?

Thanks in advance.